# How to return different shared element from first shared element when start a transition activity

Tags: android, material-design, shared-element-transition

I have an activity that contain a listview.
My listview has many pictures.
When user touch a picture, second activity start with shared element transition.
Second activity contains viewerpager that shows pictures in first activity.
I want when user press back after change current picture, return transition back to current picture item with animation.
By default sample of shared element transition,when user press back return transition animation back to first item that user touch it.

Answer (score 0):

try use `listView.setSelection(position)` in onResume method

Or for smooth scroll `listView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);`

Comment: I don't want select that item, i only want animation end in that item. Some like media viewer in telegram.

Comment: No, please wait i describe my problem in picture.

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample project: https://github.com/alexjlockwood/activity-transitions

The key point: you have to tell activity 1 a new position of shared element.